# Better technique for this?

Tags: java, if-statement, combinations

I have a Java program and I use Eclipse. My program takes in 3 values and has 3 expected values, and it decides which values are out of tolerance. I need to print which values are out of tolerance. It could be just value 1, all of them, etc. Right now I have a bunch of else if statements to cover all combinations of values that are out of tolerance.
Is there a better way to do this?
Thx!

This program works just fine the way it is. It just seems like bad code.

Current code:

```
    if (thicknessIsGood == true && widthIsGood == true && lengthIsGood == true) {
        lumberReport = "Lumber dimensions meet tolerance standards of 0.03125 inches";
    }
    //check if all dimensions are within tolerance
    else if (thicknessIsGood == false && widthIsGood == false && lengthIsGood == false) {
        lumberReport = "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance. All dimensions exceed tolerance of 0.03125 inches.";
    }
    //check if thickness is bad
    else if (thicknessIsGood == false && widthIsGood == true && lengthIsGood == true) {
        lumberReport = "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance. Thickness exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.";
    }
    //check if width is bad
    else if (thicknessIsGood == true && widthIsGood == false && lengthIsGood == true) {
        lumberReport = "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance. Width exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.";
    }
    //check if length is bad
    else if (thicknessIsGood == true && widthIsGood == true && lengthIsGood == false) {
        lumberReport = "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance. Length exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.";
    }
    //to cover all bases in lieu of 6 more else if statements (if this is wrong, please let me know
    else { 
        lumberReport = "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance. Two dimensions exceed tolerance of 0.03125 inches.";
    }
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind: don't use `== true` or `== false`. Directly check `if (thicknessIsGood)` or `if (!thicknessIsGood)`.

Comment: There are a number of possibilities here. You could use a switch statement (or expression) rather than if statements.  You can use a `Function ` for each “test”, store the functions in a list and stream through the list using a filter with each input value.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

With a little rearranging you can report which dimensions are not met.

- first store the messages in an array.
- then set the index to 0.
- set to 1 if width is bad
- add 2 if length is bad
- add 4 if thickness is bad.

Here is how the index sums up.

```
// goodWidth + goodLength + goodthickness == 0
// badWidth  + goodLength + goodthickness == 1
// goodWidth + badLength  + goodthickness == 2
// badWidth  + badLength  + goodthickness == 3
// goodWidth + goodLength + badthickness  == 4
// badWidth  + goodLength + badthickness  == 5
// goodWidth + badLength  + badthickness  == 6
// badWidth  + badLength  + badthickness  == 7
```

You have eight messages and the values in various combinations will create the appropriate index for the message and return it.

```
 private static String[] msgs = {
         "Lumber dimensions meet tolerance standards of 0.03125 inches",
         "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance.\nWidth exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.",
         "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance.\nLength exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.",
         "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance.\nWidth and length exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.",
         "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance.\nThickness exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.",
         "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance.\nWidth and thickness exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.",
         "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance.\nLength and thickness exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.",
         "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance.\nAll dimensions exceed tolerance of 0.03125 inches."};

System.out.println(getMessage(true, false, false));
```

prints

```
Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance.
Length and thickness exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.
```

The method

```
public static String getMessage(boolean widthIsGood, boolean lengthIsGood, boolean thicknessIsGood) {
    int index = widthIsGood ? 0 : 1;
    if (!lengthIsGood) {
        index +=2;
    }
    if(!thicknessIsGood) {
        index += 4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't produce the exact same output, but you could report each dimension that doesn't meet the standards.

```java
if (thicknessIsGood && widthIsGood && lengthIsGood) {
    lumberReport = "Lumber dimensions meet tolerance standards of 0.03125 inches";
} else {
    lumberReport = "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance.";
    if (!thicknessIsGood) lumberReport += " Thickness exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.";
    if (!widthIsGood) lumberReport += " Width exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.";
    if (!lengthIsGood) lumberReport += " Length exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a number as a bitmap where 1 and 0 stand for `true` and `false` respectively and respective constants in a switch-case:

```
int mask = ( thicknessIsGood ? 4 : 0 ) | ( widthIsGood ? 2 : 0 ) | ( lengthIsGood ? 1 : 0 );

switch( mask ){
  case 7: // 111 binary
   lumberReport = "Lumber dimensions meet tolerance standards of 0.03125 inches";
   break;

  case 0: // 000 bin
    lumberReport = "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance. All dimensions exceed tolerance of 0.03125 inches.";
    break;
  
  case 3: // 011 bin
    lumberReport = "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance. Thickness exceeds tolerance of 0.03125 inches.";
    break;

  // other cases

  default:
    lumberReport = "Lumber dimensions are not within tolerance. Two dimensions exceed tolerance of 0.03125 inches.";   
}
```

Comment: I'd go a little further and code a statically-initialized 8-element array to map the number to a report string.

Comment: If it were Groovy I'd definitely go for a map-literal, but for java...

Comment: It's not much more verbose in Java these days. At least not for a small number of elements. Just do `var map = Map.of(0, "a", 1, "b", ...);`. Or just do what Arfur Narf suggested: `String[] values = {"a", "b", ...}`. Arrays are already essentially an integer-to-value map.

Comment: Also, note you could use a switch expression if you're on a recent enough version of Java. It would look like: `lumberReport = switch (mask) { case 0 -> "a"; case 1 -> "b"; ... };`.

Comment: The OP might well be asking about Java 11 or even 8.